# clicking a div to check a checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I'm testing a js function to check and uncheck a checkbox with a separate div which also changes color.

The following script works when the checkbox id is typed into the function manually, but when I try to pass it in as a parameter it doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong?

```
<form action="#">
    <input type="checkbox" id="joe" name="joe">

<div id="container" style="background-color: red; width: 200px; height: 200px;" onclick="selected(this, 'joe')"></div>

<script>
    function selected(elmnt, id2check) {
        var x = document.getElementById("id2check").checked;
        if(x == false) {
                elmnt.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
                document.getElementById("id2check").checked = true;
        } else {
                elmnt.style.backgroundColor = "red";
                document.getElementById("id2check").checked = false;
        }
    }   
</script>
```

UPDATE:

Ah, just figured it out. The tutorial I was basing it on used quotation marks on the passed value. I took those off and it works now. :)

Comment: Quotes. Remove the quotes in `getElementById("id2check")`. JavaScript treats that as a string, not a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should put `id2check` without the quotes. Because with the quotes it is a string not a variable, and you want to use a variable. (The one passed to the function).

```
<script>
    function selected(elmnt, id2check) {
        var x = document.getElementById(id2check).checked;
        if(x == false) {
                elmnt.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
                document.getElementById(id2check).checked = true;
        } else {
                elmnt.style.backgroundColor = "red";
                document.getElementById(id2check).checked = false;
        }
    }   
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use plain CSS if you just want to change the style:

```
<style>
#container {
    background-color: red;
    display:block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
#joe:checked + #container {
    background-color: blue;
}
</style>
<form action="#">
    <input type="checkbox" id="joe" name="joe">
        <div id="container"></div>
```

Here is a demontration:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nikkapp/xadcb6d7/2/)

If you want to use javascript i would have written it a little different:

```
<script>
function selected(elmnt, id2check) {
    var x = document.getElementById(id2check);
    // Check if the element exists
    if (x) {
        x.checked = (!x.checked); // Turns true to false and false to true
        elmnt.style.backgroundColor = (x.checked ? "red" : "blue");
        // (isChecked ? ifTrue : ifFalse)
    }
}   
</script>
```

Hope this helped you.